# Why do you think when I upload images from my CF card to my computer some of the images are randomly corrupted?

Tags: file, download, jpeg, corrupt

It is very strange indeed.  I've uploaded several times trying different techniques and I've never had this problem before.  It is also very random.  I've uploaded the same photos to different named folders to test out the randomness and one photo is ok one time and the next time it is a blue blob and corrupted.  Super random.  I tried my Uploading Program (Downloader Pro) (never had any problems before) and it seems like it corrupted more files then just uploading the files straight from the card to the drive.  I tested this and it appears to be true.  More files are randomly corrupted using the Program I've always used vs just straight from the card to a folder on the drive.  But this isn't the solution to just go straight from card to folder because there are still some files being randomly corrupted.  What the hell right?  This all of a sudden just started to happen.  Also when I look at all the photos on my camera directly from the card there is never any corrupted photos.  Only after I download to my computer or drive. Also I've tried with several different CF Cards and even with different Cameras. Nothing changes. Still have random corrupted files on transfer. Windows 10 Pro. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It was the Card Reader. Wow that took a lot of different testing, but as it turns out it is simply the Card Reader and nothing more.  I tried everything, but that and it never occurred to me to skip the card reader and try directly from my camera.  Well it works just fine straight from my camera using both my download program and the drag and drop windows style. So now I'll get a new Card Reader and I'm sure that will solve the problem and if not well I did find a work around going directly from the camera.